# For a very niche project: how to pass a C# class to a Compute Shader and get out multiple 2d float arrays

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

I'll do my best to explain the problem, which first requires an explanation of the project. I apologize ahead of time if it's a bit scattered. I have ADHD, which has made communicating on this platform massively difficult, so please bear with me. This is necessary to mention because stack overflow has consistently suppressed my questions for being scattered and I'm tired of this intolerance.

The project generates a [3D Worley noise map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worley_noise) using my own unoptimized algorithm, which, at the moment, requires iterating through every index of the 3D array and individually calculating every element's value on the CPU one at a time. also, this will be in 3D world space.

Additionally, I needed to write my own class for the randomized points or "nodes" because this program iteratively moves these nodes in pseudorandom directions, and each node is associated with a procedure for calculating map index values, which is just assigned via an integer between 1 and 6. after each iteration, the map is regenerated. Without the nodes, this can't work.
[Code for the Nodes on repl.it](https://replit.com/@JoshuaFavorite/NodeCode#main.cs)

Obviously, this is extremely slow, and I need to implement multithreading and compute shaders, which is the conclusion I've come to. Still, I'm faced with a massive problem: I've no idea how to use hlsl or compute shaders, and I cannot, for the life of me, find any resources on hlsl for C#/java/python programmers that would help me wrap my head around anything. ANY resources explaining hlsl on a basic level would be enormously helpful.

Now, for the specific problem of this question: I have no idea how to start. I have one vague idea of an approach that is derived from my ignorance about multithreading. I could use 32 individual 32x32 `RWStructuredTexture2D<float>` arrays that I stack after calling my shader to create a 3D texture; however, to do this, I need to be able to pass my nodes to the shader, and every use of compute shaders I've seen only has one parameter, `uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID`, which makes no sense to me. I've briefly considered making a struct for the nodes in my shader, but I still have no idea how to get that information to my shader.

For the actual question: how do I throw nodes at this and then get 32 32x32 float arrays out of it?
here's some pseudocode for the in-betweens.

```
//somehow set this up to have 32 different threads
//make an hlsl equivalent of a float[,]
@params NodeSet nodes and z coordinate
@return float[32,32]
//NodeSet is just a collection of Nodes that has some convenience methods.
float[,] CSMain(@params) {
   for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
      for(int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
         //set value of element
   return floatArr;
}
```

Second question: should I even be using Compute Shaders for this problem?

Comment: So you have an arbitrary number of nodes, and regardless of the number of nodes, this should produce 32x32 float arrays numbering exactly 32? What information does the pseudocode use from nodeset? What is this `z coordinate` that is mentioned only in psuedocode? Is there exactly one z coordinate for every node or does each node have a corresponding z coordinate? Is there a maximum element count for the nodeset? Is there a minimum element count?

Comment: Also, could potentially multiple nodes influence a particular element's value? In other words, does each output value expect to read multiple nodes?

Comment: for the z coordinate: for the current version of this project, which runs everything in c# on the cpu, I iterate through every x, y, and z coordinate of the 3D noise map and calculate the value of those coordinates relative to the nodes. just basic worley noise generation. 
However, after scouring the internet for information on 3d arrays in hlsl, I came to the conclusion that they are not supported, but 2d arrays are. So I thought, I'll just construct a 3D array from many 2D arrays, and each 2D array will be associated with a z coordinate.

Comment: @Ruzihm have you read the article on Worley noise that I linked? each node's influence on an element is proportional to the distance between.

Comment: for the 32 32x32 arrays: this will be part of a chunking system, I want to use 32 as a standardized size to reduce the number of changing variables. essentially that's just an arbitrary number I chose for convenience.

Comment: imo just output a 1d array of 32x32x32 elements and the first 32 elements represent 32 indices [0,0,0-31], the next 32 represent 3d indices [0,1,0-31], basically you convert 1d index [i] into 3d index [floor(i/32/32), floor(i/32)%32, i%32] (apologies if there's a typo, hopefully the idea gets across)

Comment: I saw something like that in another question, but the explanation was much less clear than yours. I think I might use that.

Comment: So it seems like you would want 32 x 32 x 32 threads where each thread represents one element of position (id[0],id[1],id[2]), and each one loops through the nodes to include their influence over that element and each thread outputs to outputbuffer[id[0]*32*32+id[1]*32+id[2]].

Comment: IT ALL MAKES SENSE NOW. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I had no clue that threads and id were connected until you said that. and that gives me an idea of how to pass in the node data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 32 x 32 x 32 threads and output to a 1d buffer of length 32 x 32 x 32 based on the id of the thread

Pseudocode:

```
#pragma kernel PseudoCode

[numthreads(32, 32, 32)]
void PseudoCode (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    float3 pos = id; // or id - float3(15.5,15.5,15.5) to center, etc.
    int outputIndex = id.x*32*32+id.y*32+id.z;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodecount ; i++)
        outputbuffer[outputIndex] += GetInfluence(nodeData[i], pos);

    outputBuffer[outputIndex] = NormalizeOutput(outputBuffer[outputIndex]);
}
```